# how to connect a table from another server, mysql

Tags: mysql, scaling

my db is growing everyday by several tens of GB. because of this, it was decided to move several tables to another server. the speed of work is extremely critical.

1 - how to make it so that one of the databases can connect to a table from another database. I need the code directly, I can't find it.

2 - make a database on server 1 so that when making a request to the product_log table, if necessary, the database itself makes a request to the desired server.
server 1 db 1 product_log table (september)
server 2 db 1 product_log table (october)
server 2 db 1 product_log table (november)

Comment: *it was decided to move several tables to another server. the speed of work is extremely critical.* These are contradictory statements.

Comment: #1. Study FEDERATED Engine. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html #2. *if necessary, the database itself makes a request to the desired server* No, you must do this in SQL code explicitly.

Comment: what do you want to tell me that Google stores everything on one server? on the same disk? humorst

Comment: *server 1 db 1 product_log table (september) server 2 db 1 product_log table (october) server 2 db 1 product_log table (november)* A table per month - bad architecture. Study partitioning. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Comment: ```A table per month - bad architecture``` and what are the arguments that this is a bad idea?

Comment: This contradicts normal forms.

Comment: *what do you want to tell me that Google stores everything on one server? on the same disk? humorst* Do you really think that Google uses MySQL? and even some other relational DBMS? Humorist...

Comment: ```In MySQL 8.0, it is also possible to use a DATE or DATETIME column as the partitioning column using RANGE COLUMNS and LIST COLUMNS partitioning.``` from your own link about portioning

Comment: I don't understand what you want to tell me by quoting this fragment.

Comment: Please clarify what "another server" means? Is it another _physical server_ or just another MySQL _database server_ in the same _physical server unit?_ Why "the speed of work is extremely critical"? What is the impact if it's not?

Comment: two physical server with two mysql server.